# Can a Defined Name in a cell provide the data source for a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, named-ranges, excel-indirect

I have several tables of data and I've named them.  I'd like to create one PivotTable and be able to key the name of a data range into a cell and have the PivotTable reference the range named in that cell.

For example, if I could have the PivotTable data source be `=A1` and in A1 have the word `PayrollTable` which is a Defined Name referencing `sheet1!A2:G200`.

What would I need to put into the PivotTable data source for it to be able to access the name in A1 which then references the Defined Name range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDIRECT(A1)
```

[INDIRECT](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm).